# How to remove all buttons from a view in iOS 7?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can I remove all buttons from a view using iOS 7?

Here's code that works in earlier versions of iOS:

```
                for(UIView *view in cell.subviews){
                    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]){
                        [(UIButton *)view removeFromSuperview];
                    }
                }
```

Comment: I assume you are not using a xib/storyboard so can't create outlets to the buttons and hide them that way?

Comment: did you try `isKindOfClass`?

Comment: Yes,I tried isMemberOfClass also isKindOfClass also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for late reply. Actually this part of code will work until iOS 6.0, but in iOS 7.0 and onwards, the code is not working.

So finally I found the solution to remove all subview from `UIScrollview` with the following statement.

```
[scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)].
```

Answer (score 6):

First you need to get all subviews from view and then check all view is type of UIButton.For more info see this...

```
for (UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
    {
        if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [(UIButton *)view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi thank u Dharmbir for your prompt response, in the above same code only i made it.If the property is button mean its not going inside of isMemberOfClass...But its working charm as below version of ios 7.Tje problem is in ios7.. Do u have any idea?

Comment: its working proper at my end in ios7 and what do you mean by property button.And second you can use isKindOfClass instead of isMemberOfClass method.

Comment: I am sorry this code also not working...just find my code below
                    for (UIView *view in cell.subviews)
                    {
                        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                        {
                            [(UIButton *)view removeFromSuperview];
                            NSLog(@"removed");

                        }
                    }

Comment: it means i'm preety sure there may be other mistake.Because if there is a button then it will sure go inside if condition.

Comment: Just a guess, maybe its where you put this code in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  It should go after the if(cell == nil) block not inside it?

Comment: the same code working xcode4.6(iOS 6.1.2),but i run the same in xcode 5(ios7.0)its not entering with in the condition of isMemberClass

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're simply not doing a loop through the subviews.  Assuming this is a view controller:

```
NSArray * allSubviews = [self.view subviews];
for(UIView view in allSubviews)
{
    if([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {                                     
        [view removeFromSuperview];                                 
    }
}
```

You also don't need to cast "`view`" to "`UIButton *`" here because the base class of "`UIView`" is what implements "`removeFromSuperview`".

Comment: From the grid view cell i want remove all buttons...Just see that code what i did here..
                    for (UIView *view in cell.subviews)
                    {
                        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
                        {
                            [(UIButton *)view removeFromSuperview];
                            NSLog(@"removed");

                        }
                    }   its not coming inside isKindOfClass or isMemberOfClass also

Comment: it may be that you don't have any buttons in your cell view and instead it's coming from somewhere else (e.g. is the cell inside *something else*?)

Comment: [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3829898/818506) that you should use `isKindOfClass` instead of `isMemberOfClass`. What difference will it make if someone uses `isMemberOfClass`? Comment please.

Answer (score 0):

Try, this will work

```
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews) 
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        [view  removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```