# Finding all buttons within view.subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, subview, for-in-loop

I'm trying to create round buttons for a custom number pad. I want to find and modify all the buttons via this fast enumeration loop:

```
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"found a button!");
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        subview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        [subview.layer setCornerRadius: subview.frame.size.width/2.0f];
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)subview.tag);

    }
```

Doesn't work.

So I looked around and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829881/find-all-controls-of-a-type-in-a-uiview). However, even though my method appears to follow the approach outlined in the accepted answer, the `if` statement doesn't find buttons. The other answer on the page looked overly complicated for my needs.

Can someone please show me where I'm going wrong?

**Edit**

In response to @luk2303's comment:

I believe all the relevant buttons are indeed directly in `view`. Here's a screenshot of the hierarchy in the storyboard:

[image]

**2nd edit**

Per @tomer's suggestion, I modified the code:

```
for (UIControl *subview in self.view.subviews)
{
    NSLog(@"inside loop");

    if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        subview.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;
        subview.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
        [subview.layer setCornerRadius: subview.frame.size.width/2.0f];
        NSLog(@"button.tag = %ld", (long)subview.tag);

    }
}
```

Unfortunately, no improvement in the result.

**3rd edit**

Here is a printout of the subviews, which obviously doesn't included the desired buttons...

```
2016-06-12 14:27:10.352 appName[5983:3143970] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x12f6912b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x12f691020>>
2016-06-12 14:27:19.419 appName[5983:3143970] <_UILayoutGuide: 0x12f6918b0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x12f691a30>>
2016-06-12 14:27:21.988 appName[5983:3143970] <UIImageView: 0x12f691040; frame = (516 209; 49 49); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x12f6911f0>>
```

Comment: Are your buttons *directly* in `self.view.subviews`? They must not be inside nested views, your code would not find them there.

Comment: Please see clarification above...

Comment: Try replacing `UIView` with `UIControl`

Comment: Also, it can be helpful to print the content of `self.view.subviews`

Comment: Have you looked at `IBOutletCollection`s?  You could just assign all the buttons to one and iterate through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your screenshot you already have them in storyboard, so you don't need to "find" them, they're here.

Do the following :

Link all buttons to your .h file by drag & dropping from the storyboard to the .h file, using right clic or ctrl+clic. Just like if you wanted to create an outlet. (by opening the Assistant editor, the middle button on the top right of the screen).

Once Xcode asks you if you want to add Outlet, or Outlet collection, or Action, chose "Outlet Collection", and name it "AllButtons" for example.

Repeat that process for every single button, except that instead of creating a new outlet collection, link every button to that recently-created outlet collection.

Now all your buttons are a part of that collection, or array if you will.

From your .m file, you can use the property and loop on it, just like you're doing with your subviews.

```
 foreach (UIButton *button in AllMyButtons){

  // Do your stuff here.
 }
```

That's it. That's all there is to it :)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. A note about that. I first selected all the buttons and right-dragged to my .h file and created the IBOutletCollection. I assumed that the collection would thus include all the buttons, and that your mention of adding each individually might be superfluous. It wasn't. As you no doubt already know, a mass-drag only includes the first button selected in the collection, and the others do indeed have to be added individually. Gracias, amigo!

Comment: Yep, selecting multiple objects in storbyoard usually only lets you modify only the first one you selected (assuming you wanted to change a property for all buttons at the same time, for example).
The only thing you can do as a bulk is move them accross the screen

Comment: Actually, there are quite a few attributes you can bulk modify, at least in the storyboard--size, background color, font and size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By setting each UIButton's "tag" property, which can be done in Interface Builder or Programmatically:

```
      button.tag = n;    // n being whatever integer value you decide.
```

Your **IF statement**, which seems to be causing the problem, can now simply compare two integer values...

```
      if(subview.tag == n) {  // n still being the integer value you've set
         ...
         // Implement desired code for each UIButton here
         ...
      }
```

You can change the **tag** property using interface builder here:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! They've already got tags, and I tried the method you suggest prior to posting. Didn't work in my case.

Comment: Are you attempting to enumerate through the buttons prior to your View Controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method executes the view details from Interface Builder - possibly from within your viewDidLoad method?

Comment: As noted in the accepted answer above, the use of an IBOutletCollection solved the problem without worrying about the sausage making in the view. Many thanks for your comments!